# Unable to retrieve Reddit OAuth2 access token using HTTP Basic Auth, 401 failure response

Tags: angular, reddit

Following the docs here: https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/oauth2, I've been unsuccessful in trying to get an access token and can't figure out why.

I am getting the following 401 (unauthorized) response from my POST request:

```js
{
  "headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null
  }
  ,
  "status":401,
  "statusText":"Unauthorized",
  "url":"https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token",
  "ok":false,
  "name":"HttpErrorResponse",
  "message":"Http failure response for https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token: 401 Unauthorized",
  "error": {
    "message": "Unauthorized", "error": 401
  }
}
```

I double checked that my clientId, clientSecret, redirect_uri, and code are all what they ought to be. I also checked that the `btoa` function generates what I expect. I tried using the header without the 'User-Agent' and 'Content-Type' keys and it doesn't work with or without.

Here is what I am doing:

```js
getAccessToken() {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(myClientId + ':' + myClientSecret)
    })
  }

  const postData = {
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code: myCode, 
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200',
  };

  return this.http.post('https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token', postData, httpOptions )
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, I have been stuck on this for way too long.

Comment: Can you post your full error response?

Comment: Updated my post with the error response

Comment: Didn't know about oidc-client.js, I'll check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `User-Agent` string is unsafe and will be refused by the Reddit servers. Remove that - it will be automatically handled for you.
2. Make sure your redirect URI matches the redirect URI you have in your `postData` exactly. It can be easy to forget a trailing `/` slash at the end of your URI or to mix up `http` with `https` which will invalidate your grant if you have one set in your app config.

[image: successful app setup]

3. Your `grant_type` should be passed as a string, not an `Object`.

I was able to get a valid response from their API's using the function below:

```js
getAccessToken() {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(myClientId + ':' + myClientSecret),
    }),
  };

  const grantType = 'authorization_code';
  const code = myCode;
  const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:4200/';
  const postdata = `grant_type=${grantType}&code=${code}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}`;

  return this.http.post('https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token', postdata, httpOptions);
}
```

[image: valid response data]

As a final note - debugging this was relatively easy by placing a  `console.log` in the result of the `getAccessToken()` service call. It provided a clearer error message when I executed your code in one of my existing Angular applications:

```js
this.redditService
  .getAccessToken()
  .subscribe(response => console.log(response));

// Output: { error: "unsupported_grant_type" }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I copied your code exactly and am still getting the same error response. I've been logging to the console exactly how you mentioned, never got an `unsupported_grant_type` error though, always 401 Unauthorized. I'm certain my clientId, clientSecret, and redirectUri are correct since they're necessary to get the code from the previous step. Makes me think maybe the issue is coming from something else outside of this code then. Possibly CORS related?...
EDIT: looks like it's unrelated to CORS.

Comment: If you have copied my code exactly and the response you are getting is a 401 response then the only possible explanation (according to the documentation) is that your client credentials sent as HTTP Basic Authorization were invalid. Quadruple check that you used the right value as your clientID, clientSecret and that your redirectURI is exactly the same. I updated the screenshot to show the placement of the clientID and secret on app preferences for reddit.

Comment: Also keep in mind that grant codes on the reddit API are only valid for 1 hour at a time unless you specifically request a permanent code.

Comment: I checked my clientID, clientSecret and redirectURI many times, they match exactly what they're supposed to be, and yet I'm still getting the same 401...wtf.
Concerning your last comment, I am requesting a permanent token.